# How to post data to contact form 7 rest api anonymously?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, api, contact-form-7

I am trying to use contact-form-7 rest api from my frontend which is on ReactJs. When I post data to api I am facing following issue.
End point: http://example.com/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/49/

{
"code": "wpcf7_forbidden",
"message": "You are not allowed to access the requested contact form.",
"data": {
"status": 403
}
}

[Facing this issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEJjW.png)

Has anyone faced this is issue ? Or what approach should I use to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the CF7 code (contact-form-7/includes/rest-api.php, line 51),

```
if ( current_user_can( 'wpcf7_edit_contact_form', $id ) ) {
    return true;
} else {
    return new WP_Error( 'wpcf7_forbidden',
        __( "You are not allowed to access the requested contact form.", 'contact-form-7' ),
        array( 'status' => 403 )
    );
}
```

this message is returned when the current user accessing the form does not have sufficient rights.